# How to unlock the screen at the start of the laptop

Tags: password, system, lock-screen, unlock

I set two passwords, one for the screen and one for the startup. When I start the laptop, appears a dialog box that says "Enter password" with 8 spaces to type. This is before you can see any screen of the system or any other screen. Since I do not remember it, after three attempts, it appears a "System disabled" screen and I have to restart the laptop. I can not advance to anything. Please help.

Comment: That is a BIOS / System Lock password.  Check with the manufacturer of your laptop about clearing that password.  That has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: I set that password after installing Ubuntu, as an option. Many thanks for your answer Terrance!

Comment: @terrance: you could post your comment as answer

Answer (score 2):

That is a BIOS / System Lock password. Check with the manufacturer of your laptop about clearing that password.  This password is not controlled by Ubuntu.

[image]

---

Here is a list of defaults:

```
Award BIOS backdoor passwords:
ALFAROME    BIOSTAR     KDD         ZAAADA
ALLy        CONCAT      Lkwpeter    ZBAAACA
aLLy        CONDO       LKWPETER    ZJAAADC
aLLY        Condo       PINT        01322222
ALLY        d8on        pint        589589
aPAf        djonet      SER         589721
_award      HLT         SKY_FOX     595595
AWARD_SW    J64         SYXZ        598598
AWARD?SW    J256        syxz         
AWARD SW    J262        shift + syxz         
AWARD PW    j332        TTPTHA       
AWKWARD     j322                 
awkward
```

---

```
AMI BIOS Backdoor Passwords:
AMI         BIOS        PASSWORD        HEWITT RAND
AMI?SW      AMI_SW      LKWPETER        CONDO
```

---

```
Phoenix BIOS Backdoor Passwords:
phoenix     PHOENIX     CMOS        BIOS
```

---

```
Misc. Common Passwords
ALFAROME    BIOSTAR     biostar     biosstar
CMOS        cmos        LKWPETER    lkwpeter
setup       SETUP       Syxz        Wodj
```

---

```
Other BIOS Passwords by Manufacturer
Manufacturer    Password
VOBIS & IBM     merlin
Dell            Dell
Biostar         Biostar
Compaq          Compaq
Enox            xo11nE
Epox            central
Freetech        Posterie
IWill           iwill
Jetway          spooml
Packard Bell    bell9
QDI             QDI
Siemens         SKY_FOX
TMC             BIGO
Toshiba         Toshiba
```

Comment: @Rinzwind Nice edit!  =)

Comment: sometimes keeping a text file on your system for 10 years is a good thing :-D :-D

Comment: more https://bios-pw.org

Comment: @Rinzwind That is cool!  However, I have no need for it since I am no longer fixing laptops, but that is indeed a very helpful site.  =)